# Multiple async action execution order in single epic

Tags: redux, redux-observable

I'm trying to setup `loginEpic` which occurs when user logs in. This is how the logic flow should work:

Epic should start with `LOGIN_REQUEST` action. Once login promise is finished successfully, user info should be fetched with `SYNC_USER_REQUEST` action (which is basically whole other epic since this is also called when initially entering site to get user info or redirect to login). Once that finishes successfully (promise and SUCCESS/FAIL calls are handled within `syncUserEpic`), `SYNC_USER_SUCCESS` should be caught in `loginEpic` and `LOGIN_SUCCESS` should be called along with `push` action which redirects user to starting page.

This is what I have so far:

```
const loginEpic: Types.RootEpic = (action$) => 
    action$.ofType("LOGIN_REQUEST").pipe(
        switchMap(({ payload }) => 
            from(membershipService.login(payload.username, payload.password)).pipe(
                switchMap((response) => [
                    syncUser.request(), 
                    action$.ofType("SYNC_USER_SUCCESS").pipe( // I think this is the problem
                        filter(isActionOf(syncUser.success)),
                        map(r => login.success(response))
                    )
                ]),
                takeUntil(action$.ofType(["LOGOUT_REQUEST", "LOGIN_CANCEL"])),
                catchError(error => of(login.failure(error))),
                endWith(push("/"))
            )
        )
    )
```

but I'm getting

> Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async
>   actions.

I'm also cancelling `LOGIN_REQUEST`/`SYNC_USER_REQUEST` with `LOGOUT_REQUEST` or `LOGIN_CANCEL` actions and also handling login error (I'm not sure if I should also handle sync user error here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to implement it this way:

```
const loginEpic: Types.RootEpic = (action$) =>
    action$.pipe(
        filter(isActionOf(login.request)),
        switchMap(({ payload }) =>
            race(
                from(membershipService.login(payload.username, payload.password)).pipe(
                    mergeMap((token) =>
                        from(membershipService.getUser()).pipe(
                            mergeMap((user) => [syncUser.success(user), login.success(token)]),
                            catchError(error => {
                                // user fetch failed, tell login that user is responsible
                                return of(login.failure(new BaseError("6010", "User sync failed.")));
                            })
                        )
                    ),
                    catchError(error => of(login.failure(error))),
                ),
                action$.pipe(
                    filter(isActionOf(logout.request)),
                    map(() => login.cancel()),
                    take(1)
                )
            )

        )
    )
```

Based on how it works, `race` is actually racing whole first block (so not just outer `membershipService.login`, with `logout.request` action. I was not aware of this, and I thought I would need another `race` condition for `membershipService.getUser` because what I need is that `logout.request` terminate whole process (even if `login` was successful and process in middle of fetching user). As far as I could test this, it's working as expected.

If anyone has any thoughts, improvements, fixes, or anti-pattern observations, please let me know.